# Reading multiple cookies jQuery, PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to make something similar like the stackoverflow vote up for the comments.
I don't use lo-gin for users so I want to use the cookies to identify an user.

I have a script that works great except one problem. It always reads the last cookie and not all cookies previously created. So if someone up-vote, and I refresh the page, all is well and the user can't up-vote anymore. So 1 user can up-vote only once for the same comment. The problem is if I up-vote different comment the previous comment becomes available for the up-vote again for the user that already up-voted.

I'm guessing I need to read the cookie in an array or create a loop?

```
$(".comment-up").one("click", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();



    var s = parseInt($(this).next('span').text());
    var m = s + 1;
    if (isNaN(m)) {
        $(this).next('span').text(1);
    } else {
        $(this).next('span').text(m);
    }


    like = $(this).attr('name');
    if (like == "") {
        like = 0;
    }
    up_id = $(this).attr('value');

    $.cookie("like", up_id, {path:'/', expires: 365 * 10 }); //set the cookie
    <? php
    $cookies = $_COOKIE["like"];
                       if ($cookies == null){$cookies = "";}
                       $already = "already";
                       echo 'if (up_id == "'.$cookies.'")
                       { 
                         $(this).next("span").text(s);
                         $(this).after("<span class='.$already.'>You already up-voted</span>");                  
                       }
                       else{
                       ';

        ?>
        $.post("/index_api.php", {
            up_id: up_id,
            like: like
        }, function(response) {
            //placeholder                                           
        });
    return false;
     }
});
```

I'm still storing the votes in the database. Cookies handle detection if someone already voted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but the problem with what you're doing is that you're constantly overriding the existing cookie value ("like") with the last liked post, so essentially, your web app "forgets" the previously liked posts.
To target this you should either store a JSON object of all liked posts inside the "like" cookie, or create a cookie for every liked post, but that may be slightly harder to maintain.

Comment: bad_boy is correct. You're constantly changing the value of the "like" cookie, instead of adding new values on to it. I recommend you read the documentation of the $.cookie jQuery plugin (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) and take a second look at PHP's $_COOKIE documentation http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php

Comment: @Grasper First of all, you should keep in mind that cookies use a bunch headers internally. And on each request you receive and send them. And cookies have tendency to expire. The very common approach regarding storing votes for articles/comments/whatever is to create a table (that looks like so `comment_id, votes, ip`) and handle it via queries.

Comment: @bad_boy, hold on. I do store it in db. I just use cookies to identify if someone upvoted because I don't have users logged-in.

Comment: @Andrew, how it will be different from cookies if users don't lo-gin?

Comment: @Tom, you are right, I'm overriding it but even if I make it dynamic, the php part will need to be handled differently.